# Why is Spring's @Component Annotation RUNTIME?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, java-annotations

I am wondering, why Spring's implementation of the `@Component` Annotation has `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`.
Here's the official implementation from [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.java)

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Indexed
public @interface Component {
    String value() default "";
}
```

In my thought, the scanning for all Spring-Components annotated with `@Component` would be done at compile-time and all the results (annotated classes) would *somehow* be stored inside the `ApplicationContext`. I guess I am wrong, but why does this annotation need to be `RetentionPolicy.Runtime`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The component scanning is done at the startup, not at the compilation.
Also, the aspects (AOP) are created at the runtime

Comment: First of all, thanks.

SpringDocs say: 

`Weaving is the process of linking aspects with other objects to create the advised proxy objects. [...] Spring AOP performs weaving at the runtime.`
and: 
`AOP proxy: an object created by the AOP framework in order to implement the aspect contracts.`

So if I have a class annotated with `@Aspect` and `@Component`, why does `@Component` need to be RUNTIME? I would expect `@Aspect` to be runtime but not `@Component`.

Comment: @wanshurst : Spring will search the classes annotated with Component, Service, Repository, Controller... etc...
Spring is not searching the Aspect classes. But if a Component is annotated with Aspect, spring will wire the aspects.
All at RUNTIME